# Assistance with reading text file from a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm having some issues reading text files from *batch* files.

Here's the text file:

```
ABCD1
ABCD2
ABCD3
ABCD4
ABCD5
ABCD6
ABCD7
ABCD8
ABCD9 ... etc.
```

Here's the batch file:

```
@echo off
:start
Echo.
set java_home="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112"
set /p LocName= <LocName.txt
mkdir c:\CSR\%LocName%\

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool.exe -genkey -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=%LocName%.net, O=AAA, C=US, ST=Georgia, L=Atlanta" -alias V5MACHINE -keypass enterpassword -keystore C:\CSR\%LocName%\V5MACHINE.jks -storepass enterpassword -validity 1461 -keysize 2048
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool.exe -certreq -v -alias V5MACHINE -file C:\CSR\%LocName%\V5MACHINE.csr -keypass enterpassword -storepass enterpassword -keystore C:\CSR\%LocName%\V5MACHINE.jks
echo %Date% %Time% Certification request file for %LocName% stored in C:\CSR\%LocName% >>C:\CSR\Log.txt
Pause
Echo Complete!
```

Comment: Is the `text file` you've provided example data for `LocName.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for /f` loop to parse the file. `%%a` represents one line each pass.

```
@echo off
:start
Echo.
set java_home="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112"
for /f %%a in (LocName.txt) do (
  mkdir c:\CSR\%%a\
  %JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool.exe -genkey -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=%%a.net, O=AAA, C=US, ST=Georgia, L=Atlanta" -alias V5MACHINE -keypass enterpassword -keystore C:\CSR\%%a\V5MACHINE.jks -storepass enterpassword -validity 1461 -keysize 2048
  %JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool.exe -certreq -v -alias V5MACHINE -file C:\CSR\%%a\V5MACHINE.csr -keypass enterpassword -storepass enterpassword -keystore C:\CSR\%%a\V5MACHINE.jks
  echo %Date% %Time% Certification request file for %%a stored in C:\CSR\%%a >>C:\CSR\Log.txt
  Pause
)
Echo Complete!
```

Comment: Works Perfectly Thanks!